# Effective way of saving parent-child tables in MVC Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, parent-child

I am trying out MVC with Entity Framework and I am trying to understand the best ways to use EF.

I have a page where student’s info together with the father/mother info can be saved. My current code works, as shown below, but I feel like I am not doing this correctly. Is there a better way for me to do this? Do I need to call SaveChanges() twice?

The db is structured as follows;
**Person**
PersonID INT PK
FirstName Varchar(50)

**Student**
Student_PersonID INT FK
Father_PersonID  INT FK
Mother_PersonID  INT FK

The student, father and mother are all FK to the person table.

The registration view page has textboxes for the 3 persons:

```
@Html.EditorFor(s => s.Person.FirstName)    @*student name*@
@Html.EditorFor(f => f.Father.FirstName)    @*father name*@
@Html.EditorFor(f => f.Mother.FirstName)    @*mother name*@
```

The controller code looks like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(Student sm)
{
        using (var db = new SMEntities())
    {
        db.People.Add(sm.Person);
                db.People.Add(sm.Mother);
                db.People.Add(sm.Father);

                db.SaveChanges(); //save the 3 persons

                int studentId = sm.Person.PersonID;
                int motherId = sm.Mother.PersonID;
                int FatherId = sm.Father.PersonID;

                Student s = new Student();
                s.Student_PersonID = studentId;
                s.Father_PersonID = FatherId;
                s.Mother_PersonID = motherId;

        db.Students.Add(s);
                db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I am using VS2010, MVC 3, and this was modeled after the database first concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually replace your code by:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(Student sm)
{
    using (var db = new SMEntities())
    {
        db.Students.Add(sm);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

The reason why this works is that EF will add all related entities to the context (which are not attached to the context) when you add the `Student`. So, this code will insert `Student`, `Person`, `Father` and `Mother` into the database and should do exactly the same like your code.